# Subclass UIButtons

Tags: iphone, ios, css, xcode, uibutton

I have four different UIViews with custom UIbuttons(10) in each view.But I want to apply two different backgroundcolors to 5 of them in each view i.e I need to apply `each view 5 buttons -> redColor` `each view remaining 5 buttons->blue Color.`

So is there any thing like `CSS in which I can define two different global classes` in which each class will have all the properties necessary to be applied to button , and declaring that class name while creating button so that the `button will inherit all the properties of that class?`
I have gone through Google but didnot find any ...

Any idea /help would be appreciated..

Comment: It looks like you need to subclass your UIView not UIButton.

Answer (score 2):

There's no CSS way of defining the properties of a button in Objective-C, but you can subclass UIButton and create 2 main buttons, one with red background and one with blue background.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get u..Can u please tell me hw can I subclass and create 2 main buttons..I need to have 5 buttons one color and the remaining 5 the other colour..

Comment: There are a lot of examples out there, check this: http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/02/a-uibutton-subclass-creating-glossy-buttons-without-images/

Answer (score 0):

The `UIAppearance` API is the only equivalent of CSS in Cocoa Touch, so you could use this if you didn't want to use a custom subclass:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ViewController class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor];
```